# Cannot get my collection's data in meteor client side js in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have written the following code in my client side js:

```
var resolutionsQ;
Template.body.onCreated(function bodyOnCreated() {
    resolutionsQ = new Mongo.Collection("res");
});

Template.body.helpers({
    resolutions: function() {
        var res = resolutionsQ.find({});
        console.log(res);
      return resolutionsQ.find({});
    }
});
```

Then in my project folder(in terminal), i wrote:

```
meteor mongo
```

After the mongo db console started, I worte:

```
db.res.insert({title: "hello #1", createdAt: new Date()});
```

This also worked.

When I wrote this, my frontend application showed everything as expected. Then I shut down my computer, and after sometime switched it on again and tried to run my meteor application. Now I see nothing, I get no error either in server console or browser's console. I don't know what went wrong then.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a [client-side collection](http://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#client-collections) by defining the collection only in client code. A collection needs to be defined on **both** the server and the client in order to persist documents to the database.

The quick solution is to create a shared file like `lib/collections/resolutions.js` which will contain:

```
Resolutions = new Mongo.Collection("resolutions");
```

Using the new-style imports mechanism, you would create a file like `imports/api/resolutions/resolutions.js` which will contain:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Todos = new TodosCollection('Todos');
```

See [this section](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure) of the guide for more details.